# Cordova 5.3.3 - How to play local mp4 video

Tags: android, cordova, html5-video, cordova-plugins, cordova-5.0.0

I am having trouble playing a local mp4 video.

I've tried the instructions here http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=63139114&postcount=9
but it doesn't work.

I also have tried a couple of cordova plugins but they seem to work only for older version.

Currently I am using this code

```html
<video id="action" controls>
                        <source src="file:///android_asset/www/videos/jospan.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    </video>
```

Regards,

Mostafa

Comment: A common misconception is that any video will work. Not all video formats are the same, especially mp4. Read this: [When coding in HTML, why does video load on some Android devices and not others?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33081951/when-coding-in-html-why-does-video-load-on-some-android-devices-and-not-others/33094084#33094084)

Comment: I do not think that this has to do with the file type .... After some trial and error I've been able able to play the video only after moving it to the phone memory outside the app installation directory like this /mnt/sdcard/video.mp4

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the file from the folder inside the www bin about to the index.html file.

For example this taxo:

- www

  - index.html
  - videos

    - yourvideo.mp4
  - otherBins/

So you have to call the file from this bin on the source tag:

> source src="videos/yourvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4"

The video will be inside your app.

I hope this work for you!
My best!