# When coding in HTML, why does video load on some Android devices and not others?

Tags: android, html, cordova, html5-video, ionic-framework

The video I have included in my app only works on certain devices. For example, it works perfectly on iPhones, the Galaxy S6, Nexus 6, and so on. However, the video loads infinitely on the Note 4. Does anyone have a solution to this?

Here is a snippet of how I am calling the video.

```
<ion-view view-title="Compensation Philosophy">
    <ion-content has-bouncing="false"; overflow-scroll="true" >
        <div class="video-container">
            <video controls class="videox" 
                src="VideoResources/Pennacchio_Rewards_Philosophy.mov"    
                poster="VideoResources/sshot.png"></video>
                </div>
```

Comment: Please add part of your source code, how do you include video in your app, what libraries, packages you use etc...

Answer (score 0):

I think that should be mostly because of video encoding. You should try with some sample video by searching them from internet and once you find some video which is working and your video is not working, then maybe after comparison, you may be able to get find out which all formats are supported on your phone.

For example, refer:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats

Answer (score 0):

@Darshak,
Digish was close to the right answer.

From [Supported Media Formats | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)

> The table below describes the media format support built into the Android platform. **Note that any given mobile device may provide support for additional formats or file types not listed in the table**.
>
> > Note: Media codecs that are not guaranteed to be available on all Android platform versions are accordingly noted in parentheses—for example "(Android 3.0+)".

- H.263
- H.264 AVC  - (Android 3.0+) -
- H.265
- HEVC -  - (Android 5.0+)
- MPEG-4 SP
- VP8  - (Android 4.3+)  (Android 2.3.3+)
- VP9  -  -  (Android 4.4+)

You can see the different formats and when they were supported for *encoding* and *decoding*. In addition, some formats require hardware, and as the documentation says, the *mobile device may provide support for additional formats or file types*.

So to completely answer the question, if the mobile device does not provide a solution for decoding the video, then the browser does not provide a solution; and so the HTML does not provide a solution, when the browser does not have a solution.

Comment: I see, so a .mov file won't play on certain Android devices? Mine is specifically running 4.4.4. Do you think I should convert to a different file format?

Comment: To answer your questions. On #1, yes - a `.mov` file may  not play on certain Android devices. On #2, if you want the file to play on Android, yes convert it to one of the known formats. From the list above, I would not convert to HEVC.  Here is the [list of video encoding formats recommend by Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#recommendations). Note, there are two tables, one for h.264 and one VP8